# Serial Number of Harddisk connected through usb

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb

There is a dock station in which I have put a hard drive. The dock station is connected through USB, but there is no command in linux which gives me serial number of harddrive connected through USB ? Tried

```
  udevinfo -n <hard disk partion>
  hdparm -i  <hard disk partition>
```

udevinfo give some random number which is like 20 bit long but not serial number and hdparm does not give anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use lshw. Example :

```
 ~ # lshw -c disk
  *-disk                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: INTEL SSDSC2MH12
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: PPG2
       serial: LNDL107600KE110CRN
       size: 111GiB (120GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=e565a8a5
 ~ #
```

Answer (score 1):

The GNOME Disk Utility (`palimpsest`) shows a “Serial Number” for my external USB hard drive. An equivalent shell command to get this serial number would be this (for `/dev/sdf`):

```
qdbus --system org.freedesktop.UDisks /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sdf org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device.DriveSerial
```

As you have written “`<hard disk partition>`” in your question, you might also be interested in this command:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  3 23:28 2CA8109FA810699A -> ../../sdf1
```